# Complete steps to re-index solr when making a schema change

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm new to solr and using solr-4.6.0.
After setting it up, I'm able to add documents to the index. But now I want to add stem filter for the search field and updated schema.xml.
To get it working I need to re-index solr on my local machine first before making a change in prod.
Google-d for a complete set of steps or procedure to follow but didn't get any satisfactory method.
Can some one provide the steps?

Answer (score 1):

You just run the same index command again. Anything with the same unique ID (as defined in schema.xml) will get overridden on commit. If you want a clean start, you can either stop instance and delete the whole index directory or run delete all command.

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre. I was looking for the complete command to be executed.